# How to open a page in full screen from back bean in jsf?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, fullscreen

I am trying to open the page from back bean in full screen on all web browsers.

In the xhtml file in a form i am using:

```
<p:commandButton value="SIGN IN" action="#{usr.processLogin()}" styleClass="lbtn" update="growl" />
```

and in the back bean my function is like:

```
public String processLogin(){
 if ((UserDAO.getInstance().correctPassword(this.getuUserName() , encryptPassword(this.getuPassword()))==true)){
   currentUser=UserDAO.getInstance().getSpecificUser(this.getuUserName());
  UserBuilding tempUsrBuldng = UserDAO.getInstance().getUsrBuilding(currentUser.getUserId());
   if(tempUsrBuldng.getUserId() != 0)
   {   
        ExternalContext ectx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession)ectx.getSession(false);
        PerformancePageBean pbean = new PerformancePageBean();
        pbean.setUsrBuldng(tempUsrBuldng);
        session.setAttribute("performance", pbean);
       session.setAttribute("userId", currentUser.getUserId());
       uUserName = "";
       uPassword = "";

       if(tempUsrBuldng.isAppInstalled() == true)

         return "WelcomePage?faces-redirect=true";
       else

        return "CongratulationsPage?faces-redirect=true";

   }else{
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error",  "No Branch has been assigned to this user."));
        return null;
   } 
  }else{
         FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
         context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Error",  "Wrong Username or Password."));
         return null;
  }
 }
```

I want to open the returned page in full screen how can i do that?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: How would you force a new link to go full screen in plain html? Find a solution for that first and then 'port' it to JSF (not really PrimeFaces related. 99,9% of the code you posted is not related to your question and only mystifies things.

Comment: @Kukeltje do you know anyway of doing it in html ?

Comment: No, I don't but maybe google does

Comment: @Kukeltje i have tried some but they are not working well that's why asked question here. Hopefully somebody will help.

Comment: In [ask] it states to mention what ypu tried and what the results were. Please do, saves us searching and suggesting things you already tried